# Killing a JVM process using the name instead of PID

Tags: java, linux, jvm

is there any way to kill Java process with name(returned with `jps` command) instead of PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command to kill the Java process by is Process Name instead of its ProcessID.

```
kill `jps | grep "DataNode" | cut -d " " -f 1`
```

Comment: This works well. Is there any command like `jps` which can kill the java process just by specifying the Main class as argument to command. I am looking for a command like `command kill <DataNode>`

Comment: Search for javaw.exe in Task Manager and from there you can kill it.. Otherwise try this `pkill -9 -f <nameOfYourJavaAplication>`